# Storing/transporting nut brittle in tins

Tags: storage-method

I made different types molasses nut brittle for the first time tonight to give as holidays gifts. I'm going to put a little of each type in small round holiday tins that I found at a craft store. I plan on putting the tins in my check-on bag when I catch my flight. However, I'm not sure how I should package them for this! Should I wrap the contents (if so, with what?), and how can I make sure the tins stay closed during the flight? I haven't packaged using tins before so I wanted to hear your thoughts.

Comment: What sort of tins are you using?
If they are airtight, then you have potential problems with air pressure differences, which may end up with the tins buckling in on themselves.

Comment: They are definitely not airtight at only $1.50 a piece from Michaels. I can't find the exact tins online, but they are just decorative mini tins that are about 4.5x2.5"

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39632/67

Answer (score 2):

Based on your answer, here's what I would do:

- Line the tins with a bit of tissue paper, to cushion the brittle
- Use rubber bands to keep the tins closed in transport
- Wrap the tins in more tissue paper, again, to provide cushioning

Comment: Beware that if you wrap the tins, you might have to unwrap the when going through airport security.  (which slows you down)

Answer (score 2):

(note: in re-reading your question, I noticed that you said 'check-on', which I read as 'carry-on'.  I've made notes for both checked & carry-on baggage)

This might be a little bit late, but in case someone in the future has this issue again:

1. Carrying lots of little metal containers onto a plane can slow you down going through airport security.  (although, it's a bit hit and miss -- I've been stopped before for lots of things ... oddly shaped picture frames, blocks of cheese, an Apples to Apples deck, pocket wrench, rechargable batteries in their charger, etc.).  I'd likely lean towards boxes over tins if you have them available and you're carrying on.  If you're checking them it's not as much of a problem, but I've had my notes from the TSA a couple of times that my bags got searched due to things I was carrying (those were mostly electronics & lots of cables)
2. Packaging inside the container depends on how thin you've made the brittle -- the more slender it is, the higher the chance of breakage.  I'd probably put something to take up any extra space to  keep the brittle from sliding around inside the case; crushed waxed paper, etc.  If there's lots of extra space, I might line the tins with bubble wrap, and then something I'd be okay coming into contact with the food (if it was reused from my supply saved for bubble wrap appreciation day).
3. You then need to protect the containers from getting too crushed and dented ... I'd likely stack them all up and then tie them together with some string, so that most of the tops & bottoms are protected, then roll the whole thing in a shirt or other clothes (I always carry-on a change of clothes, just in case my checked luggage is delayed).  If it's in a larger bag, try to get it towards the middle of the bag, especially if it's a soft-sided bag.

Comment: Wish I would have read this sooner! Most of the brittle did arrive broken. When making the brittle, I tried to make it as thin as possible (first mistake- most of the pieces arrived broken). To transport, I put brittle in each tin, filling it about 3/4 of the way (2nd mistake- there was room for the brittle to jostle around and break). I did use large rubber bands to keep the containers closed. I placed the tins together at the top of my bag (3rd mistake) with no clothes as padding, as they were being used to protect my huge laptop. Luckily, though, I did not have any problems with security.

Comment: Sorry ... I wish I had posted it sooner.  (you asked your question weeks before Christmas; I didn't reply 'til the week after.)