# Transporting confections

Tags: food-transport

Lately I've been making a lot of chocolate truffles. The problem is, if you put them in a plastic box and drive them somewhere, they rattle around in the car, and end up dented and scratched. How can I prevent this?

Obviously the way the professionals do this (i.e., if you *buy* a box of chocolates) is to put them into a custom-shaped plastic tray which exactly matches the shape and dimensions of the individual confections.

Now I could buy a box of chocolates and keep the box, but I rather doubt that my home-made sweets would just happen to fit in the same tray. (Their size and shape tends to be rather random.)

Any better suggestions?

Comment: I see no reason to think this is off-topic.

Comment: How soft would you say your truffles are? I use rice inside cling film like pillows/duvets to pad between layers, but if your truffles are soft it may cause them to flatten.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/39632/67

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option is paper **candy cups** (or foil if you're feeling fancier). This is how chocolates are "nestled" in place in many candy boxes when there's no pre-molded tray, there's flexibility in the size of candy that can fit in them, and they are pretty widely available.

Image below is from an Amazon listing. I've also seen them in craft stores and some cooking stores, and there are doubtless lots of internet sources.

[image: picture of foil cups]

Comment: Those in conjunction with the egg cartons could be the best answer yet!

Answer (score 7):

This actually works: Egg Cartons. If you call around, you will likely find people willing to give you hundreds of them.

Comment: That was going to be my answer :) I additionally suggest nestling them in a bit of tissue paper in each of the egg pits (holes? nests?), for additional cushioning as well as slight decorative effect.

Comment: Not the most awesome presentation, but definitely protective

Comment: @sq33G actually "prettying" them up could be a fun craft project.

Answer (score 7):

I've just recently started making my own chocolate confections and have been pondering this very problem. The only thing I've come up with so far is to get some soft tissue paper and scrunch it up and place it in the container. The chocolates can then be pushed into the various crevices and the paper holds each one in place and keeps it separate from its neighbours. Then scrunch up a second piece of paper, place it on top and put the lid on the box, making sure that the lid compresses the top layer slightly to hold it firmly in place.

This should keep the chocolates in good condition as you transport them.

I guess you could package multiple layers this way too, although I've not tried that (yet).

Comment: +1, this is what's worked for me, for anything that I don't want to rattle around (crumbly cookies, pills in a jar, etc., etc.). If you use some nice-looking multi-layer soft tissues (rather than, say, toilet paper, although even that works in a pinch) and pull the individual layers apart before *gently* scrunching them, you can even make it look pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

Are you transporting them to a place where they are going to be plated so the actual packaging doesn't matter? How about mini-muffin tins? You could get a 24-count tin and anchor it in a pizza box.

Answer (score 0):

If your truffles are food art as in modernist cuisine, silicone hemispheric molds would keep them from any movement at all.